# Regarding oracle server sharing issue?

Tags: database, oracle

i have a local oracle server installed in my machine.one of my collegue want to share the same server in my machine through the network.Is it possible to access the database in my machine from my collegue machine? if so,tell me the steps to share the database between 2 or more users?

Answer (score 1):

Generally he will need client software of some sort (eg SQL*Plus, SQL Developer).

Say your machine is on the network as 10.2.0.101 and the database instance is XE (default for the free Express Edition), he should be able to connect from SQL*Plus using a

> sqlplus user/pass@10.2.0.101:1521/XE

There can be a number of barriers to a successful connection (including firewalls on either his machine or yours, or not being on the same network). For fuller details, you should post the relevant operating system(s) and what software your colleague wants to use to access the database.

Answer (score 0):

He will need a TNSNAMES.ORA entry for your database service.